# Eloquent insert or update query

Tags: laravel

I have a settings table which i am trying to update. My table is empty and i need to insert some data into it.

I am using eloquent to insert

```
  $s = new Settings;

  $s->language = request('language');
  $s->sitename = request('sitename');
  $s->user_id = Auth::id();
  $s->save();

  return redirect('settings');
```

I have come across this function

```
$se = Settings::findOrNew($id); // if exist then update else insert
```

The `findOrNew` requires me to know the id before i can save.

How can insert or update without knowing the id(which may not even exist in the first place).

Comment: your basis for condition is the `user_id`?

Comment: Yes,that would be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in that cause you can use `firstOrNew`

since you said your basis is you wanted to check if that `user_id` already exist in table then you use it as condition instead of `id`

first -> you use `firstOrNew`
    this function do is

1. check if condition exist it then if it exist it will just return the first existing data
2. if not just insert a new data and return the new insert data

   ```
   $s = User::firstOrNew(array('user_id' => Auth::id()));
   ```

Then -> after that you can now use that object and do what you wanted to do on it

```
    $s->language = request('language');
    $s->sitename = request('sitename');
    $s->save();
```